# PHP add events from database in calendar

Tags: php, sql, database, calendar

I have a calendar in php and now I am trying to add events from the database table into the calendar. I want to make it so that the event gets shown at the date when its supposed to be. And also that info like the event description and customer are being displayed as well.

A screen of my db table: [image]

And heres the code of my calendar.php

```
<?php
 class Calendar {  

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct(){     
    $this->naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

/********************* PROPERTY ********************/  
private $dayLabels = array("Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag","Sonntag");

private $currentYear=0;

private $currentMonth=0;

private $currentDay=0;

private $currentDate=null;

private $daysInMonth=0;

private $naviHref= null;

/********************* PUBLIC **********************/  

/**
* print out the calendar
*/
public function show() {
    $year  == null;

    $month == null;

    if(null==$year&&isset($_GET['year'])){

        $year = $_GET['year'];

    }else if(null==$year){

        $year = date("Y",time());  

    }          

    if(null==$month&&isset($_GET['month'])){

        $month = $_GET['month'];

    }else if(null==$month){

        $month = date("m",time());

    }                  

    $this->currentYear=$year;

    $this->currentMonth=$month;

    $this->daysInMonth=$this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);  

    $content='<div id="calendar">'.
                    '<div class="box">'.
                    $this->_createNavi().
                    '</div>'.
                    '<div class="box-content">'.
                            '<ul class="label">'.$this- 
                >_createLabels().'</ul>';   
                            $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     
                            $content.='<ul class="dates">';    

                            $weeksInMonth = $this- 
            >_weeksInMonth($month,$year);
                            // Create weeks in a month
                            for( $i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++ ){

                                //Create days in a week
                                for($j=1;$j<=7;$j++){
                                    $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j);
                                }
                            }

                            $content.='</ul>';

                            $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     

                    $content.='</div>';

    $content.='</div>';
    return $content;   
}

/********************* PRIVATE **********************/ 
/**
* create the li element for ul
*/
private function _showDay($cellNumber){

    if($this->currentDay==0){

        $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this- 
             >currentMonth.'-01'));

        if(intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)){

            $this->currentDay=1;

        }
    }

    if( ($this->currentDay!=0)&&($this->currentDay<=$this->daysInMonth) ){

        $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYear.'- 
        '.$this->currentMonth.'-'.($this->currentDay)));

        $cellContent = $this->currentDay;

        $this->currentDay++;   

    }else{

        $this->currentDate =null;

        $cellContent=null;
    }


    return '<li id="li-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' 
     start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
            ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">'.$cellContent.'</li>';
}

/**
* create navigation
*/
private function _createNavi(){

    $nextMonth = $this->currentMonth==12?1:intval($this->currentMonth)+1;

    $nextYear = $this->currentMonth==12?intval($this->currentYear)+1:$this- 
  >currentYear;

    $preMonth = $this->currentMonth==1?12:intval($this->currentMonth)-1;

    $preYear = $this->currentMonth==1?intval($this->currentYear)-1:$this- 
  >currentYear;

    return
        '<div class="header">'.
            '<a class="prev" href="'.$this->naviHref.'? 
   month='.sprintf('%02d',$preMonth).'&year='.$preYear.'">Zurück</a>'.
                '<span class="title">'.date('Y M',strtotime($this- 
      >currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-1')).'</span>'.
            '<a class="next" href="'.$this->naviHref.'? 
           month='.sprintf("%02d", 
         $nextMonth).'&year='.$nextYear.'">Weiter</a>'.
        '</div>';
}

/**
* create calendar week labels
*/
private function _createLabels(){  

    $content='';

    foreach($this->dayLabels as $index=>$label){

        $content.='<li class="'.($label==6?'end title':'start title').' 
   title">'.$label.'</li>';

    }

    return $content;
}



/**
* calculate number of weeks in a particular month
*/
private function _weeksInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

    if( null==($year) ) {
        $year =  date("Y",time()); 
    }

    if(null==($month)) {
        $month = date("m",time());
    }

    // find number of days in this month
    $daysInMonths = $this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);

    $numOfweeks = ($daysInMonths%7==0?0:1) + intval($daysInMonths/7);

    $monthEndingDay= date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$daysInMonths));

    $monthStartDay = date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));

    if($monthEndingDay<$monthStartDay){

        $numOfweeks++;

    }

    return $numOfweeks;
   }

  /**
  * calculate number of days in a particular month
   */
  private function _daysInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

    if(null==($year))
        $year =  date("Y",time()); 

    if(null==($month))
        $month = date("m",time());

    return date('t',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));
         }

   }
```

Comment: Inlined image, edited formatting of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got your code working.

```
   <?php
  class Calendar {  

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct(){     
    $this->naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

/********************* PROPERTY ********************/  
private $dayLabels = array("Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag","Sonntag");

private $currentYear=0;

private $currentMonth=0;

private $currentDay=0;

private $currentDate=null;

private $daysInMonth=0;

private $naviHref= null;

/********************* PUBLIC **********************/  

/**
* print out the calendar
*/
public function show() {

    // change this to your credentials
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = "usbw"; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "test"; 

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

    try { $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());} 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 


    $dates = array();

   foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM events") as $row){
       $event = array();

       $event['kundenname'] = $row['kundenname'];
       $event['auftrag'] = $row['auftrag'];
       if (array_key_exists($row['termin_datum'], $dates)){
           array_push($dates[$row['termin_datum']], $event);
       }
       else{
           $dates[$row['termin_datum']] = array();
            array_push($dates[$row['termin_datum']], $event);      
       }
     // now all events are inside an array
   }



    $year  = null;

    $month = null;

    if(null==$year&&isset($_GET['year'])){

        $year = $_GET['year'];

    }else if(null==$year){

        $year = date("Y",time());  

    }          

    if(null==$month&&isset($_GET['month'])){

        $month = $_GET['month'];

    }else if(null==$month){

        $month = date("m",time());

    }                  

    $this->currentYear=$year;

    $this->currentMonth=$month;

    $this->daysInMonth=$this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);  

  $content='<div id="calendar">'.
                '<div class="box">'.
                $this->_createNavi().
                '</div>'.
                '<div class="box-content">'.
                        '<ul class="label">'.$this->_createLabels().'</ul>';   
                        $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     
                        $content.='<div class="dates">';    

                        $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month,$year);
                        switch($month){
                            case "01":
                            $min = 0;    
                            break;
                             case "02":
                            $min = 3;    
                            break; 
                            case "03":
                            $min = 3;    
                            break;
                            case "04":
                            $min = 6;    
                            break;
                            case "05":
                            $min = 1;    
                            break;
                            case "06":
                            $min = 4;    
                            break;
                            case "07":
                            $min = 6;    
                            break;
                            case "08":
                            $min = 2;    
                            break;
                            case "09":
                            $min = 5;    
                            break;
                            case "10":
                            $min = 0;    
                            break;
                            case "11":
                            $min = 3;    
                            break;
                            case "12":
                            $min = 5;    
                            break;
                            // this are the numbers of empty fields
                            // you should get those numbers from somewhere, these numbers are only working for 2018. 
                            // replace these numbers by the number of empty fields where the month starts with.

                        }


                        // Create weeks in a month
                        for( $i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++ ){

                            //Create days in a week
                            for($j=1;$j<=7;$j++){
                                if (array_key_exists($year."-".$month."-".sprintf("%02d", $i*7+$j-$min), $dates)){

                                   $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j, $dates[$year."-".$month."-".sprintf("%02d", $i*7+$j-$min)]);  
                                }
                                else{
                                    $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $content.='</div>';

                        $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     

                $content.='</div>';

$content.='</div>';
    return $content;   
}

/********************* PRIVATE **********************/ 
/**
* create the li element for ul
*/
public function _showDay($cellNumber, $appointment = NULL){

if($this->currentDay==0){

    $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-01'));

    if(intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)){

        $this->currentDay=1;

    }
}

if( ($this->currentDay!=0)&&($this->currentDay<=$this->daysInMonth) ){

    $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYear.'- 
    '.$this->currentMonth.'-'.($this->currentDay)));

    $cellContent = $this->currentDay;

    $this->currentDay++;   

}else{

    $this->currentDate =null;

    $cellContent=null;
}

if($appointment != NULL){
    $c = '<div id="li-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' 
 start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
        ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').' busy"><span>'.$cellContent.'</span>';
        $c.= "<ul>";
        for($w=0;$w<count($appointment);$w++){
            $c.= "<li> - ".$appointment[$w]['kundenname']."</li>";
        }
        $c.= "</ul>";

        $c.= '</div>';
}
else{
    $c = '<div id="li-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' 
 start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
        ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').' free"><span>'.$cellContent.'</span></div>';
}    


return $c;    

}

/**
* create navigation
*/
private function _createNavi(){

    $nextMonth = $this->currentMonth==12?1:intval($this->currentMonth)+1;

    $nextYear = $this->currentMonth==12?intval($this->currentYear)+1:$this->currentYear;

    $preMonth = $this->currentMonth==1?12:intval($this->currentMonth)-1;

    $preYear = $this->currentMonth==1?intval($this->currentYear)-1:$this->currentYear;

    return
        '<div class="header">'.
            '<a class="prev" href="'.$this->naviHref.'? 
   month='.sprintf('%02d',$preMonth).'&year='.$preYear.'">Zurück</a>'.
                '<span class="title">'.date('Y M',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-1')).'</span>'.
            '<a class="next" href="'.$this->naviHref.'? 
           month='.sprintf("%02d", 
         $nextMonth).'&year='.$nextYear.'">Weiter</a>'.
        '</div>';
}

/**
* create calendar week labels
*/
private function _createLabels(){  

    $content='';

    foreach($this->dayLabels as $index=>$label){

        $content.='<li class="'.($label==6?'end title':'start title').' 
   title">'.$label.'</li>';

    }

    return $content;
}



/**
* calculate number of weeks in a particular month
*/
private function _weeksInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

    if( null==($year) ) {
        $year =  date("Y",time()); 
    }

    if(null==($month)) {
        $month = date("m",time());
    }

    // find number of days in this month
    $daysInMonths = $this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);

    $numOfweeks = ($daysInMonths%7==0?0:1) + intval($daysInMonths/7);

    $monthEndingDay= date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$daysInMonths));

    $monthStartDay = date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));

    if($monthEndingDay<$monthStartDay){

        $numOfweeks++;

    }

    return $numOfweeks;
   }

  /**
  * calculate number of days in a particular month
   */
  private function _daysInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

    if(null==($year))
        $year =  date("Y",time()); 

    if(null==($month))
        $month = date("m",time());

    return date('t',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));
         }

   }

 $calendar = new Calendar(); 
echo $calendar->show();
```

Comment: I call the calendar by using this code: $calendar = new Calendar();
 
echo $calendar->show();

Comment: After changing the code as directed by you I get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$dates' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /var/www/vhosts/toolmaster.ch/doriansandbox.toolmaster.ch/calendar.php on line 14. EDIT: Fixed it by puttinb private before the date array. But now I get this:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'try' (T_TRY), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /var/www/vhosts/toolmaster.ch/doriansandbox.toolmaster.ch/calendar.php on line 15

Comment: @DorianNY the query is just an example on how I would do it, just be sure you run a query and loop through the results.

Comment: change this: `try {         
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename"); //where db is db connection
    $stmt->execute();
}

catch(Exception $error) 
{
  echo '<p>', $error->getMessage(), '</p>';
}` into your code

Comment: did that still same error. And yeah I changed the db variable to con since I use that for my db connection and changed table name but still got same error

Comment: @DorianNY you can remove the try, catch story, its not necessary

Comment: ty but now I just got another error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /var/www/vhosts/toolmaster.ch/doriansandbox.toolmaster.ch/calendar.php on line 15

Comment: @DorianNY  `for($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){` this should also be your code, $stmt doesn't exists if you use yours

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I m using.. Would be awesome, if you could help me fix the problem and get the calendar up and running. Need to finish the website for my firm by the end of the week.

Comment: yes, i would like to, but i can't see any results, so do u have a site where the code is running or something?

Comment: yes u can check it out here: But before that you have to login. Just use username test and password test http://doriansandbox.toolmaster.ch

Comment: Can I see the code running without errors? So remove the DB querys for a sec

Comment: could you send me the css you are using?, do this in private chat please, so I can simulate and use it on my localhost

Comment: Sure thing, but how can I invite you to chat or enter your chat. I found chatrooms but no way to invite u

Comment: Fml dont have enough repo to chat there.. any other idea as to how we could chat. Maybe over google hangouts ?

Comment: I have a option, give me your email

Comment: @DorianNY check my edited answer and send the CSS code to : jelle@ozmo.nl